# Chtml::link reverses the order of the link

Tags: yii

I really cannot understand what is going on. The Url manager is turned off. What's even more strange is that when I hover over the link, the link path is correct, but when I click on it, inspect element shows a strange link order, and I get 404 error.

- on hover: index.php?r=action/controller&id=180"
- inspect: index.php?r=action/controller&id=180"
- on click:  index.php?ajax=grid-id&id=180&r=action/controller

correct one is the hover one. on click is completely wrong and weird. Why is it getting my grid id? I can't understand.

How would it take the grid id and append it in my url? and then use id then action/controller?!

grid:

```
'value'=>function($data){
if (intval($data->id) ==Yii::app()->user->id){
return CHtml::link("[X]",  array("action/controller","id"=>$data->pid),                 array('confirm' => 'Are you sure? ',                        'class'=>'stat-active'));
}
....
```

Is it something related to this? I have it elsewhere, they seem to work fine.

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('stat-active', "
    $('#grid-id a.stat-active').live('click', function() {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('grid-id', {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    success: function() {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('grid-id');
                    }
            });
            return false;
    });"
);

?>
```

[edit] full grid:

```
    <?php
        $this->widget ( 'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array (
                    'type' => 'striped condensed',
                    'id'=>'grid-id',
                    'dataProvider' => $active,
                    'template' => '{items}{pager}',
                    'columns' => array (
        array (
                'name' => 'effective_to_date',
                'header' => 'Effective To',
        array(
                'header'=>'Notes',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::link(substr($data->des, 0, 70)."...",
                Yii::app()->createUrl("action/controller/details", array("id"=>$data->artid)), array("data-toggle"=>"modal","data-target"=>"#message_modal","content" => "$data->des"))',),
        array(
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>function($data){
                    if (intval($data->aProd->user_id) ==Yii::app()->user->user_id()){return CHtml::link("[X]",  array("action/controller","id"=>$data->aId),array('confirm' => 'Are you sure? ','class'=>'stat-active'));
    }
else { if(intval($data->bProd->user_id) ==Yii::app()->user->user_id()){
return CHtml::link("[X]", array("action/controller","id"=>$data->bId),array('confirm' => 'Are you sure? ','class'=>'stat-active')
                );
                }
            }}
        ),
    )));?>  

<?php $this->beginWidget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbModal',
    array('id' => 'message_modal',
)); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if(url){
        $(target).find(".modal-body").load(url);
    }
});

</script>
<div class="modal-header" id="messages">
    <p style="font-size: 18px">Notes</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="messages">
    <p></p>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Comment: please show full gridColumn with button

Comment: updated...also included other stuff

Comment: actually it works fine for me, maybe some other scripts influence on this link

Comment: really? but I dont get why? I changed the id of the grid as well. Okay, well thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here you might have to use url manager. enable your url manager form config/main.php..

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'rules'=>array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\S+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                ),
        ),
```

this will manage your url like this

```
index.php/controller/action/180
```

try this. i hope this will help you

thank you.